# how to reduce number of variables and make the code efficient

Tags: python, random, passwords

this is first time i am posting to stackoverflow

what will be the efficient way to create and use such variables

```
lowerCharsEnabled = True
upperCharsEnabled = True
digitCharsEnabled = True
specialCharsEnabled = True
```

this function does the job but according to me its not the most efficient way of doing this

```
def usedChars():
    global finalChars

    if lowerCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = lowerChars

    if upperCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = finalChars + upperChars

    if digitCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = finalChars + digitChars

    if specialCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = finalChars + specialChars
```

looking forward for suggestions any help would be appreciated

full program code for reference

```
import random
import string

lowerChars = string.ascii_lowercase
upperChars = string.ascii_uppercase
digitChars = string.digits
specialChars = string.punctuation

lowerCharsEnabled = True
upperCharsEnabled = True
digitCharsEnabled = True
specialCharsEnabled = True
finalChars = ""

passLen = 8

def usedChars():
    global finalChars

    if lowerCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = lowerChars

    if upperCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = finalChars + upperChars

    if digitCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = finalChars + digitChars

    if specialCharsEnabled == True:
        finalChars = finalChars + specialChars


def generatePass():
    try:
        password = "".join(random.choice(finalChars) for x in range(passLen))
        print(password)

    except:
        print("Cant Generate Pass")

usedChars()
generatePass()

input("Waiting...")
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Would be more suitable for this type of question.

Comment: First, use `secrets.choice` for passwords rather than `random.choice`

Comment: Second, have the function take arguments and return the result with `return`, rather than global variables

Comment: Pretty much any python tutorial will have examples and exercises for writing a function that takes arguments and returns the result; that may be more efficient...

Comment: at the very basic level, you'll need to learn python naming conventions, for eg: `lowerCharsEnabled` should be renamed as `lower_chars_enabled` instead and so on...

Comment: The `try`/`except` isn't really any use like this; omit it?

Comment: Generally, going through any python tutorial will help you solve many of the problems in this code; then you'll be in a much better place to ask about what's left

Comment: Definitely never use `random` for passwords, though; `secrets` does a much better job

Comment: made all the suggested improvements lots of learning

Comment: Since your code actually works, and you're not really asking for a solution to a coding problem, you should post this question on a review site, like @goion suggests

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on a code review site

Comment: @Grismar i was looking forward for efficient way for defining variables and python conventions which was solved thanks the question is now answered

Comment: Don't test boolean variables for equality to `True`, just give them descriptive names and use them.  For example, `if lower_chars_enabled == True:` should be `if lower_chars_enabled:`.  Otherwise you're just setting up for a disaster when `==` morphs to `=` via a typo or downstream maintenance by a "helpful" colleague.

Comment: I've just rolled the question back to how it was originally posted. the comments don't make much sense if you change it as you go along and  your changes just made it the same as your "answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Answer thanks to everyone

```
import string
import secrets

lower_chars = string.ascii_lowercase
upper_chars = string.ascii_uppercase
digit_chars = string.digits
special_chars = string.punctuation

lower_chars_enabled = True
upper_chars_enabled = True
digit_chars_enabled = True
special_chars_enabled = True
final_chars = ""

passLen = 8

def used_chars():
    global final_chars

    if lower_chars_enabled == True:
        final_chars = lower_chars

    if upper_chars_enabled == True:
        final_chars = final_chars + upper_chars

    if digit_chars_enabled == True:
        final_chars = final_chars + digit_chars

    if special_chars_enabled == True:
        final_chars = final_chars + special_chars



def generate_pass():
        password = "".join(secrets.choice(final_chars) for x in range(passLen))
        return password

used_chars()
generate_pass()

input("Waiting...")
```

Comment: this is slightly better than the code you posted, but it would be significantly improved if you incorporated more of the suggestions.  [global mutable state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/366707) being the my biggest worry.  i.e. learn about parameters and return values then use them

Comment: @SamMason I agree, I cringe whenever I see that `global`.  I tell my students that it's a red flag to use either parameterization/return or OOP.